# Using ng-repeat in directive with isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

`ng-repeat` inside a directive with isolated scope is not picking up the property that's passed through `'='` binding.

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div my-directive list="users">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in list">
                {{item.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
        { name: 'John Doe'},
        { name: 'Jane Doe' },
        { name: 'Jesse Doe' }
    ];
});

app.directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            list: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    }
}]);
```

Above code works fine with angular 1.0.8:
http://jsfiddle.net/shazmoh/4DN39/7/

but not with angular 1.2.14:
http://jsfiddle.net/shazmoh/4DN39/6/

What got changed with '1.2.x' that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

From the [migration to 1.2 guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#isolate-scope-only-exposed-to-directives-with-scope-property):

> **Isolate scope only exposed to directives with scope property**
>   Directives without isolate scope do not get the isolate scope from an
>   isolate directive on the same element. If your code depends on this
>   behavior (non-isolate directive needs to access state from within the
>   isolate scope), change the isolate directive to use scope locals to
>   pass these explicitly.

So, with > 1.2.0, isolated directives are completely *isolated*.

Comment: "Directives without isolate scope do not get the isolate scope from an isolate directive on the same element." -- Isn't it opposite to the scenario mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Davin Tyron From the documentation: `The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection. Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given loop variable is set to the current collection item, and $index is set to the item index or key.` Clearly ngRepeat creates an isolate scope, and shazmoh's code clearly creates one as well.